# CROSS DOMAIN, I want to receive *.zip file from a another domain (No server access)

Tags: javascript, web, dns

Is there any possiblity to receive/display data from another domain?

the data types are zip, mp3, jpg, etc...

I'm making a web site based on javascript, html, js, ect....

## I can't access or edit Server.

## Only client access.

ex)

Client : http://aaa.com/index.html (I'm here)

Server : http://bbb.com/flower.zip

I Want to read on bbb.com/flower.zip

Help me!

thank you!

(No use chrome plug-in or --disable-web-security)

Comment: Since I assume you on, create an endpoint on your own server that downloads it and sends it back.

Comment: What do you mean you want to read the file? Like you want the JavaScript on the client page to download and decompress the zip file?

Comment: yes! want to decompress zip file and view on the client page.